# PredicateBuilder returns all users predicate.Or

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, predicatebuilder

I'm developing a library with C#, Entity Framework Code First 4.4.0.0 and .NET Framework 4.0.

I have this code:

```
string[] keywords = null;
if (query_string != null)
    keywords = query_string.Split(' ');

// Check parameter. It will throw an exception.
ParameterCheck.CheckObjectId(user_id);

// Convert parameter to int.
int userId = Int32.Parse(user_id);

try
{
    using (var context = new AdnLineContext())
    {
        context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

        //IQueryable<User> query = context.Users;
        IQueryable<User> query = context.Users.AsExpandable();
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<User>();

        foreach (string keyword in keywords)
        {
            string temp = keyword;

            predicate = predicate.Or(u => u.Name.Contains(temp) ||
                                     u.State.Contains(temp) ||
                                     u.HashTags.Contains(temp));
        }
        query.Where(predicate);
        query.Include("WhoHasBlockedMe").Include("Friends");

        var users = query.ToList();

        [ ... ]
    }
}
```

if `keywords = {"john", "happy"}` I want to get this SQL:

```
select * from users where
users.name like '%john%' or 
users.state like '%john%' or 
users.hashtags like '%john%' or 
users.name like '%happy%' or 
users.state like '%happy%' or 
users.hashtags like '%happy%';
```

**How can I do that with PredicateBuilder?**

By the way, I have downloaded LinqKit from http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

**UPDATE**
I have added a breakpoint at `var users = query.ToList();` and `query` has this SQL:

```
{SELECT 
[Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId],
[...]
FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]}
```

It doesn't have a `Where` clause.

Comment: @pasty Nope, that wouldn't change anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
query.Where(predicate);
query.Include("WhoHasBlockedMe").Include("Friends");

var users = query.ToList();
```

`.Where` and `.Include` don't *modify* the underlying query, they *return* a new query.

Use

```
query = query.Where(predicate);
query = query.Include("WhoHasBlockedMe").Include("Friends");

var users = query.ToList();
```

instead.

Comment: ... or use the beautiful dot notation.

Answer (score 1):

What's the result of `true OR something Or SomethingElse`?

Do you even need to know what `something` is?

It will always be `true`.

You need to start out with `False`, not `True`.  `False Or anything` is equivalent to `anything`.

If you were AND-ing items, you'd start with true, given that `true AND anything` is equivalent to `anything`.

Comment: Yes, I've started with False, and change it to True because with False it returns all users.

Comment: @VansFannel With `true` it will always return all users no matter what.  With `False` it will generate the proper query.  You'll need to show the SQL that's actually generated to see how it differs from what you want, beyond that.

Comment: With false it returns all users.

Comment: @VansFannel Then you have some other additional problem, besides just this.

Comment: I've updated my question with the SQL statement in `var query`.

Comment: @VansFannel Print out `predicate` and see what it has.